# Different names for different objects of same type

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects which are all the type 'person' but I would like the array to contain maybe something like 'person0', 'person1', etc. I currently have this:

```
var population = [];
var populationCount = 0;

function person(id,age){
    //simplified version
    this.id = id;
    this.age = age;
}

function createPerson(){
    population[populationCount] = new person();
    population[populationCount].id = populationCount;
    population[populationCount].age = 0;

    populationCount ++;
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    createPerson();
}
```

The array currently contains "person, person, person, ..." but I would like it to contain "person0, person1, person2, ...".

Why I think this would be useful  ...
if let's say population[100] would die, that would be the person with the id of 100, population[101] would take its place, assuming I just simply use population.splice[100] when he dies. So now population[100] has the id 101 and now it would be useful if the array of population would contain different 'names' so you could use indexOf to get the index of any specific person ...

Comment: Why not use an object (key-value) in that case?

Comment: @UnholySheep because I don't want the values of the objects themselves but rather the objects in the array just with different 'names' not person, person, person

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. What is an object's "name" supposed to be? It has no meaning in terms of code, because you can use a variable with any name to refer to an object. Also what exactly is the use-case for this? You can access array elements only via the index, so how would you use this "name"?

Comment: When you say it just contains `person, person, person, ...`, I'm assuming you're looking at some version of this logged to the console.  Usually there's some way to expand the element in such a list to see their contents.

Comment: *"so you could use indexOf to get the index of any specific person"* Why do that at all when you have an `id` property that you can simply look at?

Comment: @ScottMarcus because the id would be of no use when the index is 'wrong' as in the example where the index of the person with the id of 101 is 100

Comment: Is it wrong?  If I was the 101st person born and the 100 people who were born before me die, am I still not the 101st person born?  The `id` will maintain the "creation" order, but your array index will maintain your youngest to oldest order. The index is all you need. `Person[100]` may have an `id` of `101`, but the index is `100`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus true but how do I find that person? I can't use the id because that doesn't match with the index and I can't use indexOf ... so what do i use ?

Comment: @frankakn_7 See my updated answer with a solution that "resets" the `id`s at your will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are confusing a type with an identifier.**

Each instance that you make is an instance of a `person`, that's not going to change. Object types are object types - - `person[6]` is still an instance of a `person`.

The `id` property or an index would be the best approaches to differentiate one instance of `person` from the next.

Also, your structure is a bit off here. `person` is a constructor function that takes two arguments, but you don't pass those arguments when you construct a person. Instead you are setting them as properties, which is OK, but counter-intuitive to the way your code is written. And, your `createPerson` function should decouple the creation of the person from the addition of it to the array.

This structure would be a better approach:

```js
var population = [];
var populationCount = 0;

// By convention, constructor funcitons should be Pascal-Case
function Person(id,age){
    //simplified version
    this.id = id;
    this.age = age;
}

function createPerson(){
  // To make this function more true to its name, just have it return
  // a new Person. It shouldn't be this funciton's job to know where
  // or how that Person is going to be used.
  
  // Also, just pass the arguments that the function is expecting
  return new Person(++populationCount, 0);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  // Here, you have a plan for how to use the Person, so here is where
  // you should add it to the array. By decoupling the addition of the
  // Person to the array from the creation of the Person, the "createPerson"
  // function becomes more useful.
  population[populationCount] = createPerson();
}

console.log("The population consists of: ", population);
console.log("The last person in the population is: ", population[population.length - 1]);
console.log("The third person in the population is a: ", population[2].constructor.name);
console.log("The third person in the population has an id of: " + population[2].id);
```

If you are concerned about indexes not matching `id`s, you could always create a "reset" function, like this:

```js
var population = [];
var populationCount = 0;

function Person(id,age){
  this.id = id;
  this.age = age;
}

function createPerson(){
  return new Person(++populationCount, 0);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  population[populationCount] = createPerson();
}

// Now, kill off the first 5 people:
population.splice(0,5);
console.log("First 5 people are gone. Array now contains: " + population.length + " people.");
console.log("First person's id is: " + population[0].id);


// *****************************************************************************
// Create a new array with the old members, but update the ids
var newPopulation = [];
function rePopulate(ary){
  newPopulation = ary.map(function(element){
    element.id = newPopulation.length + 1;
    return element;
  });
}
rePopulate(population);

console.log("The array has been recreated and ids have been adjusted");
console.log("First person's id is now: " + newPopulation[0].id);
```

And, if you want to be able to find a Person in the array based on the `id` without knowing what the corresponding index is, you can do this:

```js
var population = [];
var populationCount = 0;

function Person(id,age){
  this.id = id;
  this.age = age;
}

function createPerson(){
  return new Person(++populationCount, 0);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  population[populationCount] = createPerson();
}

// Now, kill off the first 5 people:
population.splice(0,5);
console.log("First 5 people are gone. Array now contains: " + population.length + " people (id's 6 - 10).");
console.log("First person's id is: " + population[0].id);


// *****************************************************************************
// With a simple "find" function, you can locate the correct person based on 
// their id and you don't have to worry about the index at all.
function findPerson(id) {  
  return population.find(function(p){
     return p.id === id;
  });
}

var x = 7; // Whatever id you are looking for
console.log("Person with id of 7 is: ",  findPerson(x));
```

Comment: easier would be just saying :

Comment: for(var i in population){

Comment: sry about that ... easier would be just saying: `for( var i in population){ population[i].id = i; }` I used this but it didn't work since I used the id's in different arrays and i needed to reset all of them ...

Comment: @frankakn_7 Do not use `for/in` loops on arrays. They are meant to loop over object properties. Using `Array.map` as I have shown would be the correct thing to do.

Comment: @frankakn_7 I think your desired result is a wild goose chase and one that you have an unrealistic expectation for. Array indexes can and do change and object properties can as well. Why is it so important that the index match the `id`?

Comment: You are right it is a wild goose chase that's why I wanted to have something that never changes but since that does not work I have to use my old version of doing everything

Comment: And it is important that the id and the index are the same because I use the id for a lot of stuff and just use the id to find the object in the array

Comment: @frankakn_7 I'm sorry, I just don't understand what you are after here. You do have something that won't change (unless you change it), the `id`. But, then you say that you do need that to change. This just isn't a use case I've ever heard of before. Again, why must the index be the same as the `id`?

Comment: I need something to find the object in the population array

Comment: Sorry to keep pushing, but why is `id` not sufficient for that task and (ahem) why does the index need to be the same as the `id`?

Comment: Id needs to be the same as the index because then I can use Population[id] otherwise I can't

Comment: In a function where the id of that person is used

Comment: This can be accomplished quite easily. Instead of directly accessing the array with an index that must match the `id`. You create a simple "find" function that takes an `id` and returns the person with that `id`. This works just like your original code, but instead of calling the array, you call the function. See my updated answer (3rd code snippet) for example.

Comment: That is actually something that could be very handy I have honestly never heard of the .find() thank you very much :D

Comment: You're welcome. This is why myself (and others) were so confused by your requirement that the indexes and the `id`s be the same. There are a number of ways to get what you need without imposing that requirement.

Comment: coming back to this question 6 years later makes me cringe eternally at my approach to programming... I admire the patience you had to explain something so trivial, despite myself continuously not accepting the answer... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By saying you would like to have person0, person1, person2, ... You are saying you want infinite number of different types, not just different objects. I do not know of a way to dynamically create types. As said in the comments, you would have to key-value pairs. Why not give each person a unique identifier, which I believe you are already doing.

You could have those objects nested within an object, say:

```
var persons = [
    { 
        person0:
        {
            id: 0,
            age: 69,
            name: 'john doe'
        },
        person1:
        {
        ...
        },
        ...
    }   
]
```